# Вывод только активных постов

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать вывод постов из таблицы `events` только тех кто имеет в столбце `active` параметр `active` .

Пока сделал только по условию

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `events` ORDER BY `add_event` DESC LIMIT 4";  
$row = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($row)){
    ?>  
    <?php if ($result['active'] !== "active" ) { ?>
   <?php } else {  ?>
    <div class="EeventPageSmall"> 
        <img src="<?php echo $result['image']; ?>" alt="logo_event">
        <p><?php echo $result['title']; ?><br> 
            <span>Дата - <?php echo $result['add_event']; ?></span><br>
            <span>Організував - <?php echo $result['post_event']; ?></span>
            <a href="../pages/big_events?event=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </p>
    </div>
<?php }} ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `active` = 'active' ORDER BY `add_event` DESC LIMIT 4
```